# c# trace log to file not working

Tags: c#, logging, trace

I am writing a small program in C# and as a part of it I need it to write data out to a log file.
for this I am using the next command:

```
 Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Constants.LOG_FILE_NAME));
 Trace.AutoFlush = true;
 Trace.Indent();
 Trace.WriteLine("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n" + DateTime.Now + ": start writing to file");
```

It works perfectly when running from visual studio, but when I am compiling a release version, it does not writing the log file and instead (sometimes) I am getting a file with the name `0` and zero size, and there is no content inside it.

I am suspecting this is a permissions problem, how can I check if this is the reason?
If someone familiar with this issue and can help me with that I'll be thankful.

**Edit**
I forgot the mention that the 'Define Trace Constant' is checked in the build properties under all the configurations, so this can't be the reason.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769085/net-trace-to-a-file-not-working

Comment: Do you have `Define TRACE constant` enabled in build properties of Release configuration?

Comment: yes I had enabled it already

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a trace switch, and then add configuration to your app.config to enable the switch. Instructions are here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t06xyy08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx